# Creating subset from timestamp In SQL or R

Tags: r, postgresql, timestamp, subset

I have a data-set which contains number of tables. I have to accomplish a process which needs a same dimension(size) for all the tables.

I have to create sub-set in 2 scenario:

1-Create sub-set based on timestamp (yyyy-mm-dd hour:min:sec)(timestamps column data type is varchar):

1.1. I need a sub-set refers to a specific period of time:
From 2004-08-12 To 2004-09-02

1.2. Create sub-set from aformentioned sub-set based on time:
From 8:00:00 To 20:00:00

2-Create subset based on number of records:
Asking for a first 10000 records of data.

Moreover, I am using R software and simultaneously applying RPostgreSQL package. So I can use both Sql and R commands.

Comment: Show the `create table` or the `\d my_table` output in `psql`

Comment: If you show sample data and expected results it's way easier to understand what you actually want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are describing a fairly simple query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM the_table
WHERE tscolumn::timestamptz BETWEEN DATE '2004-08-12' AND DATE '2004-09-02' 
  AND extract(hour FROM tscolumn::timestamptz) BETWEEN 8 AND 20
ORDER BY tscolumn;
LIMIT 10000;
```

To get a reasonable selection of rows with a `LIMIT` you need an `ORDER BY`.

See the [manual for `extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html).

It's pretty weird to store a timestamp in a `text` or `varchar` column, though. Why would you do that?

Comment: Actually, yyyy, month, day, hour, min, sec all were in separate columns and for combine them then I have used following code:   (update s2 set dt= year || '-' || month || '-' || day || ' ' || hour || ':' || min || ':' || sec). Initially, I created a table and aforementioned command did not run in timestamp format and I have changed it to varchar.

Comment: It is not clear but I understand that he wants 3 separate results. And the last one has no filters.

Comment: @aliamidi That is bad. Can you change that to a single `timestamp` column?

Comment: @Clodoaldo, it is already in a single column. You mean, changing the format?

Comment: @aliamidi Ok. Missed the `update`. I mean in addition to just one column also change the type from `varchar` to `timestamp`.

Comment: @Clodoaldo Meh, it's not worth guessing and producing many different variants for an unclear question. Let ali clear it up.

Comment: @Clodoaldo,          Thanks for your support. I can run the code, but it returns "data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows"

Comment: @aliamidi This answer is from Craig

Comment: @CraigRinger, I want to preform cross-correlation among 10 station. I have a separate table for each station. And each station, contatin values for different time intervals. I have to somehow aggregate them to the almost same time intervals.Or in other words,the dimension of the station should be the same.

Comment: @Clodoaldo, Sth interesting, as i mentioned I am using R software and there is package celled RPostgreSQL as a tool for connecting to the Postgresql. The code returns nothing in R but it works properly in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @aliamidi Sounds like you want `UNION` (for combining the tables). For grouping up time intervals you can either use range queries as shown in my example, or use `date_truc` to reduce the timestamp precision; see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html